# Generate Unique batch IDs in Oracle

Tags: sql

I need to batch insert some rows in a temp table and later delete them. What i need a unique id which can specifically identify and delete rows which are inserted in a single transaction. How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

I want to place a few rows in a temp table using batch insert, use it to do some joins etc with other tables in db,  and delete those rows after it is done. So once the data is used, I should be able to delete them. There might be many users using this temporary table simultaneously hence I need some unique id to specify rows inserted in a single insert so that they can be deleted with a simple delete statement without deleting the rows other users enter at that time
  delete from table where  = 'xxx'

Comment: Do you have the structure of the temp table, where you've to insert rows?

Comment: Create a sequence, then use `seq_name.nextval` during insert.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If I understand the OP correctly, (s)he wants to have the *same* Batch ID for all rows inserted in a single transaction (something like a load ID for an ETL process).

Comment: @FrankSchmitt: a sequence could still be used for that using nextval and currval.

Comment: @sanjana nair: Why don't you use a real temporary table? This gives you session-private data for free, without having to worry about accidentally deleting other user's data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach is to use a sequence to generate your Batch ID beforehand and then provide that Batch ID to your INSERT statement:

```
create sequence seq_batchid;

declare
  l_BatchID number;
begin
  /* if you're using release 10 or earlier, use 
  select seq_batchid.nextval into BatchID from dual; 
  instead */  
  l_BatchID := seq_batchid.nextval; 

  INSERT INTO temp_table(BatchID, ...) (SELECT l_BatchID, ...)
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle sequence might work. But to confirm that, you need to give us more information about what you are trying to achieve. It would be good if you can give us the table structure too.